# Keep these buttons centered, but have no gap in between them?

Tags: css

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I need to keep these buttons centered, the way they are, within their wrap, but I need both buttons right up against each other, so that it almost look like one big button.  I've had to make each button display:inline, to keep them centered. When I try to float both buttons so that they are up against each there, then I lose the whole thing being centered.  I threw it in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xe2YV/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply remove the white space from in between the tags, or comment it out ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe2YV/1/)).

```
<div id="buy">
 <div id="buttons-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="index-buy-price">$5</a><!--
  --><a href="#" class="index-buy-button">Grab This Deal</a>
 </div><!--end buttons-wrap-->
</div><!--end buy-->
```

Comment: Dangit! See! I knew it was something simple! Thanks a ton, this will work great.